# Overflow Error in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

Below is my code for the project I am doing, and for some reason I keep on getting an overflow error at the line:

```
totalAmountWeight = (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Info").Cells(p, 8).Value) / (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Info").Cells(p, 7).Value)
```

I am not sure why this error is occurring or how to fix it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim target As Range
Set target = Range("Q1")
Dim p As Long
Dim o As Long

Dim r As Long
Dim Length As Single
Dim Width As Single
Dim Height As Single
Dim totalAmountWeight As Double
Dim i As Integer, intValueToFind As Integer





Dim sheet As Worksheet

Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Info")
'lastrow = sheet.Cells(sheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

o = 1
r = 1

If Not Intersect(target, Range("Q1")) Is Nothing Then

For p = 2 To lastrow


Length = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Info").Cells(p, 2).Value
Width = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Info").Cells(p, 3).Value
Height = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Info").Cells(p, 4).Value



totalAmountWeight = (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Info").Cells(p, 8).Value) / (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Info").Cells(p, 7).Value)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Range("O1").Value = totalAmountWeight

Call boxes(Length, Width, Height)
Call boxesLast3(Length, Width, Height)

intValueToFind = 0
For i = 2 To 7    ' Revise the 500 to include all of your values
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Cells(i, 5).Value = intValueToFind Then
        'MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Cells(i, 7).Value = 600
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Cells(i, 8).Value = 400
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Cells(i, 9).Value = 325

        Else
            'MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")
            'MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Cells(i, 5).Value
    End If
Next i


Call LWextra(Height, Length, Width)
Call HWextra(Height, Length, Width)
Call LHextra(Height, Length, Width)
Call HLextra(Height, Length, Width)
Call WLextra(Height, Length, Width)
Call WHextra(Height, Length, Width)


newamount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Range("Q1").Value
dimensions = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Range("K13").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Cells(o, 26).Value = newamount
o = o + 1

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend").Cells(r, 27).Value = dimensions
r = r + 1

Next p

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you dividing it by zero ? Use `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Info").Cells(p, 7).Value` or step through the code. Check the value in Immediate window using `Ctrl + G`

Comment: Did you have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525290/overflow-error-6-in-excel-vba-double or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965805/incorrect-vba-overflow-using-doubles-excel or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955488/vba-overflow-error-with-type-double-excel ?

Comment: What are the values for the numbers you are dividing when you get the error?

Comment: @newguy wouldn't that give a division by zero error?

Comment: You are also trying to use alphabetical row headers when they need to be numeric using the 'cells()' function.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes you are right but I didn't say that's the cause of that error. But it's good to check with what values you are using to do the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I just printed it out, and I saw that I have an extra blank space being printed. I just somehow need to get rid of that blank space.

Comment: @Ralph I didn't notice that.  Glanced quickly.  Apologies